# Java regex expression to match at least one of Scandinavian alphabets

Tags: java, regex

I want to evaluate a text if it contains at least one Scandinavian alphabet and it is ok with no whitespace or more than that. What did I wrong?
I tested this string:

```
String nor = " a d f ø ø å æ ";


if(s.matches("[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ]+[\\s]*"))
```

Comment: you just want to get a true/false against the rule?

Comment: What behavior are you observing?

Answer (score 3):

`Matcher#matches` matches the whole `String`. Therefore the regular expression should match the entire `String`. You can use a `.*` prefix to match characters outside the character classes:

```
if (s.matches(".*[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ]+[\\s]*") {
   // Functionality related to Scandinavian expression
}
```

Comment: I am going to use this matches function in another product, namely Confluence plugin, so I cannot use Matcher class.

Comment: I meant that I cannot use Pattern class ^^;

Comment: In that case why not just use `s.matches(".*[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ]+[\\s]*")`?

Comment: Perfect, why do you not write your answer as own post, so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 1):

This regex will match any text that contains a Scandinavian character:

```
.*[æøåÆØÅ].*
```

(Remember to use DOTALL if your text could contain newlines.)

Comment: but does it not match ONLY these alphabets? I need to include a - z as well.

Comment: The . character stands for anything, so it will match any string at all if that string contains one or more Scandinavian characters.

Comment: no, my requirement is if that whole text has at least one alphabet, then it is ok. Not one particular word that must contain these three alphabets.

Comment: This regex meets that requirement. Is there a string that you want to match which isn't getting matched?

Comment: I tried this, but my mentioned string does not get matched...  ´if(s.matches("[a-zA-Z]+.*[æøåÆØÅ].*[\\s]*"))´

Comment: Yes it does! Make sure you copy-pasted my regex exactly -- and I'm assuming that your actual code checks `nor` for a match rather than `s`.

Comment: Use the regex I gave you -- the code you posted uses a different regex. If you copy-paste it exactly it should work.

Comment: I copied your regex and it works as expected, but I do not wish to include any character, only a-zæøå and whitespace. So thanks for the help.